# Type vim in terminal open macvim?

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

I just installed macvim for the ease of installation and integration with Ruby and Python already built in. I know I can just double click on the vim.app icon to open a new window, but how can I make it so that if I am in terminal and type "vim" it will open the vim that macvim newly installed instead of the one that comes on mac.

Right now if I type in "vim" I get the one that was preinstalled, but I want it to open macvim. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macvim normally is opened from the command line with

```
mvim
```

---

If you take the `mvim` script that came with MacVim and plave it in `~/bin` (or symlink it if you prefer)

Then in your `~/.bashrc` add the following line.

```
export PATH="~/bin:$PATH"
```

Then execute

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

This will place `mvim` in your PATH so that you can execute it.

---

If you want to alias vim to open macvim you can add the following to your `~/.bashrc` (if `mvim` is not in your path)

```
alias vim=<full path to mvim>
```

If mvim is in your PATH you should just be able to put

```
alias vim=mvim
```

Comment: I get command not found.. I just stuck the unzipped folder into /Applications/ which contains MacVim, mvim, and README.txt

Comment: @mharris Add mvim to your PATH.

Comment: @mharris7190 see edit

Comment: I don't have ~/.bashrc ? no such file or directory... Is there something I am missing?

Comment: @mharris7190 just create missing files or directories

Comment: Note that you can run MacVim's CLI executable *in* your terminal with `$ mvim -v`.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just aliasing it in my .profile. I've never messed around with this PATH stuff before so I learned some new things. Thank you!